NullReferenceException Message=The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class
Exception: System.NullReferenceException  Message=The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class.
Where I'm getting this issue: While hitting the API using httpclient as below
var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content);

Please help me with your suggestions
Environment: .NET 8, Android, MAUI, Visual studio.
Situation: I upgraded the Android Xamarin (.NET Framework) application to MAUI.
MainActivity Class:
[Activity(Name = "Test.MainActivity", Label = "Test Mobile", Icon = "@drawable/icon"
    , LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme"
    , ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    // for FCM push notifications
    internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "fcm_notification_channel";
    internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

    enum EnvCheckType { Root, Debug, Emulator, Hooks, CustomFirmware, IntegrityCheck, WirelessSecurity };
    static BitArray envChecks = new BitArray(7);

    private MyBroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            Instance = this;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogErrorAsync(ex);
        }
    }
}

MainApplication:
[Application]
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    // for FCM push notifications
    internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "fcm_notification_channel";
    internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

    enum EnvCheckType { Root, Debug, Emulator, Hooks, CustomFirmware, IntegrityCheck, WirelessSecurity };
    static BitArray envChecks = new BitArray(7);

    public MainApplication(nint handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership) : base(handle, ownership)
    {
    }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
        
        return builder.Build();
    }
}

I tried making multiple changes regarding the Mainactivity and HttpClient but nothing worked


Try to migrate Xamarin project to MAUI manually? This can avoid some trivial issues. 2.  Put builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit(); and FCM push notifications codes into MauiProgram.cs intead of MainApplication.


About this error:

NullReferenceException Message=The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class

You can add this code:
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

And try to put builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit(); and FCM push notifications codes into MauiProgram.cs intead of MainApplication.
Update:

How can i execute the MainActivity class logic before execution of the
App class logic.

Unfortunately it can't do that. When you add breakpoint in MainActivity and App class, it will execute App class firstly.

@jianwei-sun-msft But my MainActivity is executing after execution of the App class because of "builder.UseMauiApp().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();" configuration in MauiProgram. So I'm getting the same issue. How can i execute the MainActivity class logic before execution of the App class logic. Thank you.

I updated the answer, you can check it.
